# Is the exponential function continuous for complex numbers?

Tags: complex-numbers, exponential-function

Hey this might be a dumb question so here it goes:

Is $e^{(x)}$ continuous for $x\in \mathbb{C}$?

Specifically this question arose while solving the differential equation in the form of

$\dfrac{dy}{dx}=\dfrac{y}{x}$ with the solution $y=cx$ and was curious if it was possible for $c=0$ in the context of complex numbers.

Thanks and be gentle, I'm an engineering student.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is continuous. It is well-known that $f(z)=e^z$ is even holomorphic, which means it's complex differentiable.

Comment: I guess I'm a little confused on how it is continuous when(I'm not aware of any) exp(x) = 0 does not have a solution in the complex numbers

Comment: I think you confuse it with the logarithm. This functions has severe problems in $\mathbb C$. We have for example $e^{2\pi i}=1$ but also $e^0=1$. Therefore, the logarithm cannot be defined on the whole complex plane.

Comment: You're one hundred percent correct I totally asked the wrong thing

Comment: @thebmags : I know of no reason why the fact that $f(z)=0$ fails for all $z\in\mathbb C$ should mean that $f$ is not continuous on $\mathbb C$.  Maybe you need to ask about something related to that. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 2):

If you know that if $x,y$ are real and $e^{x+iy} = e^{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}(\cos y + i\sin y)$ and that the functions involved in putting that last expression together, you can deduce that that function of $x+iy$ is continuous (provided you know several basic facts about continuity).

If you know that $\displaystyle e^z = \sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{z^n}{n!}$, and that, as shown by a ratio test, that series converges, then you can deduce that $z\mapsto e^z$ is continuous if you know some basic theorems on convergent power series.

If you know that $z\mapsto e^z$ is differentiable and that differentiable functions are continuous, that also does it.